# ¿Como abrir un JFrame desde otro mediante un botón?

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

Tengo un JFrame en el cual hago click en un botón y llama a otro JFrame, pero no sucede nada solo desaparece el primer JFrame, quiero saber que es lo que sucede.

Este es el código que uso para abrir el JFrame:

```
try {           
    FrmClientes Clientes = new FrmClientes();
    Clientes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(false);
    Clientes.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e);
}
```

añadí un try-catch para ver si había error y nada. Este es el código inicial del segundo JFrame:

```
public FrmClientes() {

    initComponents();

    mostrar("");
    ocultar_columnas();

    RbApellido.setSelected(true);
    Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
    DcFecha_Ingreso.setCalendar(fecha);
    inhabilitar();

    BtnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
    BtnEliminar.setEnabled(false);

    BtnCancelar.setEnabled(false);    
}
```

Comment: ¿`public FrmClientes()` es una clase que sería un JFrame? En ese caso debería extender de JFrame . Para probar, si pones algo como esto: `JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Probando si se ve");` `myFrame.setVisible(true);`  en lugar de `Clientes.setVisible(true);` creo que verás aparecer una JFrame. Significa que la JFrame que estás queriendo llamar no es en realidad una JFrame.

Comment: Se necesita el código completa (por lo menos la declaración de clase) de FrmClientes para poder dar una respuesta.